# Java Executor Framework Efficient way of performing task with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a scenario where the existing code does the following task(Single Java file and class):

```
methodCopyDataBasedOnDates(StartDate, EndDate) {
    GetDataFromSomewhere(); // Gets data from a Database table
    ProcessData(); //Converts to JSON array
    PasteSomewhereElse(); //Copies to Amazon S3
}
```

Now, since this takes a long time for this single task, I want to implement Java multithreading as a solution.
I am planning to use executorFramework like this:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<whatever> allDateRangesQueue; //Contains all date ranges.
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

while(!allDateRangesQueue.empty())
    {
               executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()

            // DatePair consists of start date and end date pair. Eg: if input date range is one year, then this DS consists of date ranges of 1 day each 364 entries in the Queue for the threads to pick up.
                        final HashMap<Integer, String> datePair = allDateRangesQueue.poll(); 
                        methodCopyDataBasedOnDates(date.get(0), date.get(1), threadName);
                    }

                });
    }
```

Question: I need a better design in terms of modularity and efficiency. Can someone suggest a design?

Comment: what does the `allDateRangesQueue` contain? it's not very clear in the code. Or is it not important to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please have a look at spring batch? I think it does exacly what you are trying to do. Will try to find a good example and update this answer

found:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ , https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-hello-world-example/

The way this works is exacly chunk asyncronous processing. you define a reader, a processor and a writer, bind these three together and these can work together in parallel. Also assuming ofcourse you can read chunks (pagination) of data, this can become a really powerfull tool.

An 'extension' that i have never managed to understand and use but if you got time it may become really usefull for you (since to me it seems that it meets your needs) is 'spring xd', but i am afraid  I failed to understand it at huge extend.  Spring batch i have used and seems like an elegant easy way to implement what you are asking for

Comment: Thanks @Alex, but I have a constraint to use POJO with executor framework.